# XPath 3.0 XML parsing functions in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-3.0

I have a sequence of strings that I need to parse as XML using XSLT. For example:

`&lt;span&gt;Foo&lt;/span&gt; &amp; &lt;span&gt;bar&lt;/span&gt; have been tagged.`

When I try to parse this using fn:parse-xml-fragment (using Saxon-PE 9.6.0.5), two errors are thrown:

1. The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
2. FODC0006: First argument to parse-xml-fragment() is not a well-formed and namespace-well-formed XML fragment.

If I remove the `&amp;` entity from the input text, then it parses correctly. However, if the entity is escaped in the input, why would it cause XML parsing to fail?

Comment: Can you please add a minimal but complete snippet that causes that error? If it is pure XPath then I don't see why the string would have any escaped markup at all, if it is inside XML or XSLT then obviously you would have a single `&` passed to the XML parser and XML does not allow that, you need it escaped as `&amp;` or inside XML as `&amp;amp;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse XML then with XML an ampersand needs to be escaped as `&amp;` and I am sure in a pure XPath context you can do `parse-xml-fragment('&amp;')`. If your input is escaped inside XML then of course you need to escape an ampersand as `&amp;amp;`:

```
<data>&lt;span&gt;Foo&lt;/span&gt; &amp;amp; &lt;span&gt;bar&lt;/span&gt; have been tagged.</data>
```

or

```
<data><![CDATA[<span>Foo</span> &amp; <span>bar</span> have been tagged.]]></data>
```

Comment: That was it--I needed to ensure that the `&amp;` entities (inside XML) were escaped as `&amp;amp;`.